# Preventing Time Discrepancies in Timer App When Moving to Background or Reopening in iOS/SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, timer, lifecycle, background-task

I'm developing a timer application using SwiftUI where users can start, pause, and resume a timer. When the application moves to the background or is closed and reopened while a timer is running, I'm experiencing time discrepancies. I have two timers running simultaneously for comparison, and when I compare the timer in my app with the other one, I notice that there is a significant deviation after moving the app to the background or reopening it. Below is the code snippet handling the timer functionality and the application lifecycle.

```
struct ActivityDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @ObservedObject var activity: Activity
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        // Other views

        Button(action: {
            activity.isPlaying.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: activity.isPlaying ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
                .foregroundColor(activity.isPlaying ? .red : .green)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            guard activity.isPlaying else { return }
            activity.currentTime += 1
            activity.totalDuration += 1
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Handle the error appropriately
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .active:
                // When the app becomes active, calculate and update the elapsed time.
                if let appInactiveTime = activity.appInactiveTime, activity.isPlaying {
                    let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(appInactiveTime)
                    activity.currentTime += interval
                    activity.totalDuration += interval
                    do {
                        try viewContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        // Handle the error appropriately
                    }
                }
            case .inactive, .background:
                // When the app goes inactive or to the background, record the current time.
                activity.appInactiveTime = Date()
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    // Handle the error appropriately
                }
            @unknown default:
                // Do nothing for other cases.
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use the app life cycle to handle the timer's state, recording the time the app goes inactive or moves to the background, and then recalculating the time interval when it becomes active again. However, I'm still observing time discrepancies. I expect the timer in my app to show the same value as the other timer I'm using for comparison, regardless of whether the app is moved to the background, closed, or reopened.

Comment: From Apple docs: „The system reserves the right to apply a small amount of tolerance to certain timers regardless of the value of the tolerance property.“

Comment: Get rid of `+= 1` and keep track of the start time. Subtract that from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Time discrepancies in timer applications can occur due to various reasons, including the app's life cycle, system resources, and CPU throttling. To improve the accuracy of your timer and reduce the discrepancies, you can consider the following approaches:

1. Use a more accurate timer: Instead of using a regular Timer, which
   can be affected by system resources and background states, you can
   use CADisplayLink or Timer.publish (available in iOS 14 and later)
   for better accuracy. For example, using CADisplayLink:
2. ack the time interval in the background: When your app moves to the
   background, the system can suspend or throttle the app's resources,
   which might affect the accuracy of your timers. To mitigate this,
   you can record the start time of your timer and the time when the
   app enters the background. Then, when the app is resumed, you can
   calculate the time elapsed during the background and adjust your
   timers accordingly.

   *Use AppDelegate to detect app lifecycle events.*